# How to access variable into function which is declared in outside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
restData = currentNode.Restdata;
chain = {
    name: currentNode.name,
    body: function (job, cb) {

        var client = restify.createClient({
            url : restData.URL
        });

        switch (restData.Type) {
            case 'GET': 
                return client.get('/​​​', function (err, req, res, obj) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb(err.name + ': ' + err.body.message);
                    } else {
                        return cb(null, 'Data found');
                    }
                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }                    
    }
};
```

In Above case, I can't access the restData variable into body: function () {}. Anyone can help me to solve this problem and i can access the restData into body function.

Let me give you an example:

This is my current json object:

```
var inputJson = {
    "nodes": [{
            "name": "Fetch Ticket from google",
            "id": 0,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 350,
            "nodetype": "restclient",
            "Restdata": {
                "Type": "GET",
                "URL": "https://google.com",
                "authorization": "OAuth2",
                "authparams": {
                    "accessToken": "xxxxxxx"
                },
                "body": [{
                    "start": "&&last_run()",
                    "end": "&&now()"
                }]
            },
            "outputConnectors": [{
                "name": "A"
            }]
        }
    ]
};
```

Now, I want to convert this json object into another format of json object by dynamically as below:

```
{
    name: "Sample Workflow",
    chain: [
        {
            name: "A Task",
            timeout: 30,
            retry: 2,
            body: function (job, cb) {
                var client = restify.createClient({
                    url : "https://google.com"
                });
                return client.get('/​​​', function (err, req, res, obj) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb(err.name + ': ' + err.body.message);
                    } else {
                        return cb(null, 'Data found');
                    }
                });
            },
            fallback: function (err, job, cb) {
                job.the_err = err;
                return cb(null);
            }
        }
    ],
    timeout: 300,
    onError: [{
        name: "Try another solution",
        body: function (job, cb) {
            cb("bhai bhul chhe kaik");
        }
    }]
};
```

And, I'm doing it by this way:

```
var workflowChains = [];
var finalWorkflow = {
    name: "Workflow 1",
    chain: workflowChains,
    timeout: 300,
    onError: []
};

var inputNodes = inputJson.nodes;
var inputConnections = inputJson.connections;
for (var i = 0; i < inputNodes.length; i++) {
    var currentNode = inputNodes[i];
    var currentConnecter = inputConnections[i];  
    restData = currentNode.Restdata;
    chain = {
        name: currentNode.name,
        body: function (job, cb) {

            var client = restify.createClient({
                url : restData.URL
            });

            switch (restData.Type) {
                case 'GET': 
                    return client.get('/​​​', function (err, req, res, obj) {
                        if (err) {
                            return cb(err.name + ': ' + err.body.message);
                        } else {
                            return cb(null, 'Data found');
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }                    
        }
    };
    workflowChains.push(chain);
}
```

And, In that case, How can I assign the https://google.com to the url in

```
var client = restify.createClient({
    url : restData.URL
});
```

Comment: You can access it just fine. Something else is amiss

Comment: I need to assign a value of restData.URL to the url into createClient.

Comment: I need to eat apples once a day. That variable is accessible within `chain`. Something else is wrong. Put a `console.log(restData)` below `restData = currentNode.Restdata;`. What does it log?

Comment: For example, restData = { URL: 'http://www.google.com' }

Now, I need to set 'http://www.google.com' to the url in 

var client = restify.createClient({
            url : restData.URL
});

while I read the client variable.

Comment: yeah, your code is correct, but I'm guessing `currentNode.Restdata;` is either `undefined` or not in the format you posted above

Comment: Yes, I can see the value of restData in below of restData = currentNode.Restdata;

Comment: What about `console.log(restData.URL)`? If it logs `undefined`, then `currentNode.Restdata` might be a `String` instead of an `Object`, thus you can't access it using dot notation and you might need to do `restData = 
 JSON.parse(currentNode.Restdata)` first

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides, I have edited the question and added the details of what exactly i want. Please check and help me to solve it.